# Open installed apps from Flex app

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, mobile, flex4

I'm developing a Flex Mobile Application. The goal I want to achieve is to be able open specific apps already installed on the device from Flex application.

Click a button and that application gets opened directly from my app.

What is the easiest way to do it? I read somewhere about ANE's but couldn't really find the one that meets my requirements or rather I don't understand how ANE's work.

What is the way to do it on Android? And what is the case for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html). It gets the package name of all the installed applications on the device. And then you can open the application by using certain validations.